# Proper way of Encoding image as base64String

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, base64

Currently, I am trying to send image to backend to upload an image in my project. I have seen all possible answer on stack overflow and elsewhere but can not successfully send the data to backend . Even if I send,due to some problem(most probably due to white spaces as I feel), image decoded in backend side is not being in proper format.

**Code to encode -**

```
let imageData1 : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(slctdImage, 0.1)!
        let base64StringNew1 = imageData1.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

***Now the intresting part -***

*When I decode that using SWIFT code locally, I get the image and I am being able to display it in an image View. But same string when I convert in any online bse64 converter, I don't get the result .*

**code used for decoding -**

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString:base64StringNew1, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
```

So what might be my problem .  **Can any one please suggest the correct way to upload images to backend using base64String?**

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
func encodeImage(dataImage:UIImage) -> String{
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(dataImage)
    return imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
}
```

Checked in http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter and works

Answer (score 0):

Below code for image encoding.

```
    let image: UIImage = imgProfilePic.image!

    let size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(image.size, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.3, 0.3))
    let hasAlpha = false
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, !hasAlpha, scale)
    image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))

    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(scaledImage, 0.9)
    var base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) // encode the image

    var cd = CoreDataUser(pstrContext: "this")

    var params = "strUsername=" + cd.getUsername()
    params = params + "&strPassword=" + cd.getPassword()
    params = params + "&blbProfilePic=" + base64String
```

PHP code where the base64 string is being decoded and displayed in the browser.

```
if ($rows) { 
    foreach ($rows as $row) { 
    $data = base64_decode($row["fblbProfilePic"]);
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
    header('Content-Type: Image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image);
//file_put_contents("test.jpg", $data);
//var_dump($data);

    //echo base64_decode($row["fblbPicture"]);
    /    /echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' . $row["fblbPicture"]     . '" />';
     }
```